# Limit of measurable function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

This question has been asked already here but I didn't get a satisfactory solution and didn't want to bring up an old question. Here is the question :

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions and define  $f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$ where the limit exists, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then $f(x)$ is measurable.

Ok So the set where the limit exists is exactly $\{x : \limsup f_n(x) = \liminf f_n(x)\}$ and this set is measurable. We are left with the set $\{x: f(x) = 0\}$ that is $\{x : \lim\sup f_n(x) \neq \lim\inf f_n(x)\}$ and I cannot prove that this set is measurable.

thanks for any pointer.

Comment: Complements of measurable sets are measurable.

Comment: Wow, so obvious ... thanks !